# Getting matplotlib to work - plots not showing

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, plot

I was able to successfully install matplotlib; however, when I run my code, I don't get an error, but instead the Python icon bouncing over and over again.

[image: Python]

I don't know if it has anything to do with

```
from rcParamsSettings import *
```

I don't have any idea what that is, but if I try to run it with that line uncommented out, I get

```
ImportError: No module named rcParamsSettings
```

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
import pylab
#from rcParamsSettings import *
import random

def flipPlot(minExp, maxExp):
    """Assumes minExp and maxExp positive integers; minExp < maxExp
       Plots results of 2**minExp to 2**maxExp coin flips"""
    ratios = []
    diffs = []
    xAxis = []
    for exp in range(minExp, maxExp + 1):
        xAxis.append(2**exp)
    for numFlips in xAxis:
        numHeads = 0
        for n in range(numFlips):
            if random.random() < 0.5:
                numHeads += 1
        numTails = numFlips - numHeads
        ratios.append(numHeads/float(numTails))
        diffs.append(abs(numHeads - numTails))
    pylab.title('Difference Between Heads and Tails')
    pylab.xlabel('Number of Flips')
    pylab.ylabel('Abs(#Heads - #Tails)')
    pylab.plot(xAxis, diffs)
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.title('Heads/Tails Ratios')
    pylab.xlabel('Number of Flips')
    pylab.ylabel('#Heads/#Tails')
    pylab.plot(xAxis, ratios)

random.seed(0)
flipPlot(4, 20)
```

What do I need to do to get the code running?

*Note*: My experience with programming and Python is very limited; I'm just starting out.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct so that users coming here in the future know what worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `pylab.show()` otherwise nothing will come up.

See the example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html

(although you should avoid using `from pylab import *`, the way you import is fine.)

There are cases in `MatPlotLib` where you do not want to show the graph. An example I have is designing a graph on a server using data collected by an automated process. The server has no screen and is only accessed by a terminal, and therefore trying to show a graph will result in an error as there is no `DISPLAY` variable set (there is no screen to display to).

In this case it would be normal to save the figure somewhere using `pylab.savefig()`, and then maybe email it or use an ftp to send it somewhere it can be viewed.

Because of this `MatPlotLib` will not implicitly show a graph and must be asked to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me if I add a `pylab.show()`.

Alternatively, you could save the plot to a file:

```
pylab.savefig("file.png")
```

This makes sense if you are updating your plot frequently.

Comment: Where does it save to?

Comment: @AlanH, it's save location is relative to `os.getcwd()`. If you don't add any filepaths aside from the filename, it will save in the current working directory. Alternatively you could get it a full filepath and it would save there (e.g. `C:/users/user/Documents/figs/myfig.png`)